# BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST on ABAP Cloud?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi, sap-business-technology-platform

On an on-premise we have option to call BAPI for CRUD operations. How can we achieve the same in SAP cloud environment. For example I am trying to find solution to post FI documents from external API into SAP Cloud, equivalent to `bapi_acc_document_post` in on-premise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cloud Environment you can enable SAP API Business Hub to access APIs described in [api.sap.com](https://api.sap.com)

There are several APIs available for different SAP Applications; for example check [Journal Entry - Post (Asynchronous)](https://api.sap.com/api/JOURNALENTRYBULKCREATIONREQUES/overview)

You can find a Business documentation describing the use cases from a functional perspective as well as technical informations (API Specs, WSDL, urls etc..)

Comment: Thanks Manuel!! Can we wrap this API in our own custom function module and expose as an RFC? some applications support only RFC